# PureScript equivalent to ‘error’ from Haskell prelude

Tags: assertion, purescript, side-effects

I’m new to PureScript and trying to find the idiom for “assertion failure”. I use this commonly to halt execution when:

- an invariant I need to rely on is broken
- a branch of the code is unreachable
- I want to defer the implementation of an expression but want that to “fail fast” at runtime (rather than just yield `undefined`)

In Haskell I would typically use the prelude function [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cafeteria-prelude-0.1.0.0/docs/Prelude-Error-Misc.html#v:error) for this kind of thing. In PureScript, I (naively) expected to be able to emulate `error` by throwing an exception and (unsafely) casting away the effect type, as below:

```
module Test.Test where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Exception (throw)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
   _ <- pure $ error "Doesn't fail"
   error' "Fails"

error :: ∀ a . String -> a
error = unsafeCoerce <<< throw

error' :: ∀ a . String -> Effect a
error' = throw
```

But this doesn't work: if I embed calls to `error` inside a large program, I end up with runtime objects with fields which are `undefined` (in the JavaScript sense), rather than a program which terminates abruptly as soon as `error` is executed. The function `throw` seems to do what I want, but it doesn't seem appropriate to pollute my program with the `Effect` type for the use cases above.

I don't object to PureScript's behaviour -- it seems reasonable that I can't cast an effectful computation to a pure one and still observe the effects. So I guess I'm missing a trick (or a library function that I haven't found yet). What's the PureScript idiom for what I'm looking for?

(The testing library `purescript-assert` provides `assert` functionality, but it too has type `Effect Unit`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [`unsafePerformEffect`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-effect/2.0.1/docs/Effect.Unsafe#v:unsafePerformEffect) - it will execute the effect in a transparent way and return its result as a pure value.

```
error :: forall a. String -> a
error = unsafePerformEffect <<< throw
```

Or, alternatively, it's very easy to FFI your own:

```
-- PureScript
foreign import error :: String -> a

// JS (foreign module)
exports.error = msg => throw new Error(msg)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Yes, looking into FFI’ng my own (along those lines) was my next step, but I’m glad to hear it’s easy to do in-language. Loving PureScript so far..

Comment: There is also [`unsafeCrashWith`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-partial/2.0.1/docs/Partial.Unsafe#v:unsafeCrashWith) which is [implemented in the same way](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-partial/blob/v2.0.1/src/Partial.js#L5) as Fyodor already suggested :-)